# Magento 2 : Flush Magento Cache Results in Site Speed Up

Tags: magento2, cache, caching, pagespeed

I've been noticing that flushing Magento cache (by clicking on the "Flush Magento Cache" button) speeds up both Magento frontend and Admin panel.

Page load speed eventually returns to a slower state, and pressing that button restores the speed.

Anyone has any clue on why this happens?